# "Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host" PHP Soap Client SSL

Tags: php, ssl, soap

I am trying to setup a Soap Client which communicate using SSL. I can able to test the Soap Request and Response in SoapUI application using my SSL certificate. It is working fine in SoapUI application.

When I try to do the same using PHP it is throwing below error.

**`"Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [HTTP] Could not connect to host in "`**

Below are the options I used in SoapClient. I also tried to add WSSecurity Header using `WSSoapClient.php`

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'ciphers' => 'TLS-RSA-AES-128-CBC-SHA'
        ),
    )
);

$options = array(
        "uri"           => $url,
        "location"      => $url,
        "soap_version"  => SOAP_1_2,
        "encoding"      => "UTF-8",
        "trace"         => true,
        "exceptions"    => true,
        "local_cert"    => __DIR__ . "/keypair.pem",
        "cache_wsdl"    => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
        "connection_timeout" => 2000
    );
```

Where `keypair.pem` is a combination of my SSL certificate (.crt) and rsa private key (.pem)

I appreciate your help in this regard.

Thanks

Sithik